# Convert latest file in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I need some help, I have the script below that converts a ".xls" file into google spreadsheet, but I need you to always use the most recent file that is in folder A, I can't do that.

```
function importXLS(){
  var folderBId = "ID FOLDER"; // Added // Please set the folder ID of "FolderB".
  
  
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById('ID FOLDER').searchFiles('title != "nothing"');
  while(files.hasNext()){
    var xFile = files.next();
    var name = xFile.getName();
    if (name.indexOf('.xls')>-1){ 
      var ID = xFile.getId();
      var xBlob = xFile.getBlob();
      var newFile = {
        title : 'backlog'+'_converted',
        parents: [{id: folderBId}] //  Added
      };
      file = Drive.Files.insert(newFile, xBlob, {
        convert: true
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can someone please help me?  It is an additional implementation of the initial code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Most recently updated file in a folder

```
function mostrecentlyupdatedfileinafolder() {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(gobj.globals.testfolderid);
  const files = folder.getFiles();
  const fa = [];
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    fa.push(file);
  }
  fa.sort((a,b) => {
    return b.getLastUpdated().valueOf() - a.getLastUpdated().valueOf();
  });
  //let fnA = fa.map(f => f.getName()).flat();
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(fnA));
  return fa[0];
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how the code will convert the file and go through the folders

Comment: can you explain me better please?

Comment: I'm simply providing a method for finding the most recently updated file in a folder.  You said you need help finding the most recent file in a folder this is a solution to that question.

Comment: Sorry if I expressed myself wrongly, my code works only with difficulty as it tries to convert all the files inside the folder, and it would be necessary to convert and transfer the most recent file to folder B.

Can you help me please?

Comment: I think I did already.  What more do you want?

Comment: sorry, it's because it's really not what I'm looking for, I tried to implement it but it didn't actually work

Comment: I disagree it does identify the most recently update file

Comment: But it's okay with me you don't have to agree

Comment: Thanks for trying friend, I understand that in fact it will return the most recent file but the idea as a whole is to merge with the initial code

Comment: yes but I don't wish to provide you with the entire solution because to do so removes the opportunity for growth.